# ViewScope beans behaves like it has application scope

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am doing work on a project using primefaces 3.5 and my problem is that...

I have a search form I enter some criteria in the form and press Search Button...Result is displayed...suppose using FireFox

Now If I open application same page in some other browser suppose IE there I will see the form with same values and same search result returned earlier...even this is a new session

More over suppose in the same browser if I logout and then login and navigate to same page I see the search form with same values and same result returned.

More or less this behavior is close to application scope Beans where as I have not any application scope Bean and have only one Bean with session scope for login purpose...rest of the beans are @ViewScoped

If I use @Scope("request")...Bean is created on each request but in this case I am unable to set parameter to the confirm dialog for deleting the record because when i click on dialog delete button previous values gets nullified due to new request.

I am in great difficulty and have done too much workaround but all in vain....

Comment: Are you just using JSF and Primefaces ? Is there any other framework ? Spring ?